# TextField suffix animation alignment

Tags: flutter, textfield, suffix

Has anybody had a similar problem?
`TextField` `sufixIcon` takes a widget like this:

```
TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
  ),
),
```

Result of the code

[image: Result of the code]

Now I would like to have the same thing but with loading animation:

```
TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Container(
    child: SpinKitWave(
      color: Colors.red,
      size: 20.0,
    ),
),
```

Result of the code with animation

[image: Result of the code with animation]

Same thing happens if I change `suffixIcon` to `sufix`.
**Question:** Right Alignment like with Icons, I tried with HorizontalAlignment doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how you can align the loading animation to the right of the `TextField` :**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.025),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(60),
                  ),
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: const Color(0xFFE3F8F8),
                suffixIcon: Container(
                  width: width * 0.2,
                  height: width * 0.1,
                  child: SpinKitWave(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    size: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: const Color(0x99000000),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]